# How close was Ahsoka to becoming a Jedi Knight?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-clone-wars, jedi-training, ahsoka-tano

Compared to a Padawan who is freshly Knighted after passing his trials, like for example Obi-Wan soon after the events of Ep. I, how close is Ahsoka at the point of her departure from the Jedi Order to achieving full Knighthood?

Answer (score 16):

How close did she come to attaining the rank? Very.

In The Clone Wars episode, *[The Wrong Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Jedi)*, she was offered the rank but turned it down. The Council considered her ordeal in hindsight as being her Trials and, having proven herself ready and worthy, offered her the promotion to Jedi Knight.

> **Saesee Tiin:** You have shown such great strength and resilience in your struggle to prove your innocence.
>
> **Ki-Adi-Mundi:** This is the true sign of a Jedi Knight.
>
> **Mace Windu:** This was actually your great trial. Now we see that. We understand that the Force works in mysterious ways, and because of
> this trial, you have become a greater Jedi than you would have
> otherwise.
>
> **Yoda:** Back into the Order you may come.
> <sub>*[Star Wars: The Clone Wars - The Wrong Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Jedi)*</sub>

Realistically speaking (in Legends, which was canon at the time), she was quite a ways away from completing her training. (all emphasis mine)

> **Padawans typically maintained the Master-Padawan partnership for a decade**, though no set time table was put in place by the Council.
> <sub>*[Padawan (Legends)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padawan/Legends)*</sub>

But since it was a time of war, this could, and did, vary.

> At the end of the Golden Age and the start of the Clone Wars, the
> Order entered into service with the Grand Army of the Republic and
> took up military titles. As in past wars, all able-bodied Jedi took to
> arms, and Padawans were given the rank of Commander over their troops.
> **Standard procedures were ignored to a lesser degree throughout this
> conflict**, but some small allowances were made in the name of
> expedience.
>
> **Many Padawans were promoted faster than was usually viewed as appropriate**, and fewer Jedi were being transferred to the Jedi Service Corps than before.
> <sub>*[Padawan (Legends)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Padawan/Legends)*</sub>

So had the events of *[The Jedi Who Knew Too Much](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Who_Knew_Too_Much)*, *[To Catch A Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/To_Catch_a_Jedi)*, and *[The Wrong Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Jedi)* not happened, Ahsoka would have had many more years before being allowed to take her Trials. Ultimately, however, Ahsoka was one "yes" from becoming a Jedi Knight.

Answer (score 12):

Based on the comments of several Jedi masters in the episode "The Wrong Jedi," it seems she would have been made a knight almost immediately if she remained in the order.

> Saesee Tiin: You have shown such great strength and resilience in your struggle to prove your innocence.
>
> Ki-Adi-Mundi: This is the true sign of a Jedi Knight.
>
> Mace Windu: This was actually your great trial. Now we see that.

Comment: I agree, but if they were saying this out of guilt from wrongly accusing Ashoka then this might mean that she may not have qualified as a knight yet following the traditional standards

Comment: she had fairly well proven herself entirely capable in terms of martial and tactical capabilities during the war prior to the events of "The Wrong Jedi" - the events of which highlighted her sense of justice, truth, honor, and mental fortitude, as well as self-control (ie - not going off the rails and raging) - if one considers the requirements to be two sided - mental and physical, then she had proved herself worthy by any standard imo

Answer (score 0):

I think that Ashoka would have become a knight very soon. That is, if the council had believed her and she hadn’t walked away from the order. But if it hadn’t been a time of war, she wouldn’t have been accused of the bombing and the bombing wouldn’t have happened. If the council had had the sense to believe her, she wouldn’t have walked away.

Comment: The only part of this that really addresses the question is the first sentence. Could you [edit] this to focus more on the question that was asked and provide evidence to back it up?

Answer (score 0):

Ahsoka was 17 by the end of the CLone Wars. She was born 36 BBY *(Star Wars Fact File)
By 22BBY would have made her 14. So she'd be 17 by 19 BBY (Episode III). Not old enough to be knighted. Even Anakin wasn't knighted til at least 20+.